# The tabs are trying to escape from the 10k delete tools!

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, meta, 10k-tools

I was looking through the mSE [10k tools delete tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tools?tab=delete), and it seems that the date range chooser gizmo has seen the meta split confusion as a chance to make a break for it. We must catch it before it goes too far!

[image]

Chrome on OS X, no weird zooming (100%).

Comment: (It's due to the 2px bottom border on the `.youarehere` tab)